# Button"+" is not being clicked in selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Source code:

```
<input type="button" value="+" id="hour_add" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all" role="button" aria-disabled="false">
```

My code:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[contains(@id, 'hour_add')]").click();
```

This button is not clicked.

Comment: <input type="button" value="+" id="hour_add" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all" role="button" aria-disabled="false">

Comment: why are you not using **element id** for identifying the element ?

Comment: We have function that handles to click buttons, so we have to use xpath

Comment: Why create a function to click buttons? It's a one-liner function??? What's the advantage over just putting the single line in your code? I don't understand people's fascination with creating functions in cases like this... Now you have a ridiculous requirement that you have to provide an XPath because someone thought it was a good idea to write a one-line function that requires an XPath. /rant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There could be multiple reasons for the problem and there is certainly not enough information to answer, but here are the possible reasons:

- there are *multiple elements matching the XPath expression* and a wrong element is clicked
- you might need to *move to the element and click*:

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

  ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(element).click(element).perform()
  ```
- you might need to *scroll into view of the element*:

  ```
  driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", element)
  ```
- you might need to *click via javascript*:

  ```
  driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element)
  ```
- you might need to [wait for element to be clickable](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/waits.html#explicit-waits):

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

  element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
      EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "hour_add"))
  )
  element.click()
  ```
- sometimes even *maximizing the browser window* can help:

  ```
  driver.maximize_window()
  ```

Comment: I update my codes with this xpath: "//div[@aria-describedby= 'Create_Development_Request']//input[contains(@id, 'hour_add')]" to specify the page that this button should be in. Also add codes to wait WebDriverWait(driver, medium_timeout).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, steps))).  Also window is already in the maxi size

Comment: thanks a lot, I use ActionChains, it did work. Have a nice weekend~~

Answer (score 0):

When you have **Id** available for the element you want to click on, then just use `find_element_by_id`.

```
driver.find_element_by_id('hour_add').click()
```

Comment: have to use xpath. I use more accurate xpath:  "//div[@aria-describedby= 'Create_Development_Request']//input[contains(@id, 'hour_add')]"

Comment: @xiaoyanzhang that's not a more accurate XPath, it's just more complicated. Why do you have to use XPath? XPath is slower and more fragile. You shouldn't build a framework around XPath.

Comment: @JeffC  Thanks for your comment. You know , not every component have  a id, but everyone has xpath. That is why we build a framework around Xpath. Is there any better choice? I am new in Selenium, but I plan to learn more about Selenium that is interesting.

Comment: There are more ways to get an element than just ID. Take a look at the Selenium wiki section on [locating elements](http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp#locating-ui-elements-webelements) for more methods.